# Python: Update column X value if the value of column Y is in a list L of possible values

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataframe with a list of bus stop ids and the hub is 'none'. I need to update the dataframe such that - if the bus stop id is in the list a_ids then its corresponding hub should be a, if in b_ids then hub=b and so on.

```
a = pd.DataFrame(({'stop' : ['10388','10382','10383','10387','10389','25568'],'hub' : ['none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none']}))
a_ids = ['10388','10382','10383']
b_ids = ['10387','10389','25568','10381']

a
```

I have tried:

```
a[(a.stop.isin(a_ids)),'hub'] = 'a'
```

I understand my approach is flawed; Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(({'stop' : ['10388','10382','10383','10387','10389','25568'], 
                   'hub' : ['none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none']}))

a_ids = ['10388','10382','10383']
b_ids = ['10387','10389','25568','10381']
print (a)

# Output
    stop    hub
0   10388   none
1   10382   none
2   10383   none
3   10387   none
4   10389   none
5   25568   none
```

Just use `loc` along with `isin`.

```
a.loc[a.stop.isin(a_ids), 'hub'] = 'a'
a.loc[a.stop.isin(b_ids), 'hub'] = 'b'

output:

    stop    hub
0   10388   a
1   10382   a
2   10383   a
3   10387   b
4   10389   b
5   25568   b
```